# Why do I have white space on the right side of the website I'm building?

Tags: html, css, css-position, margin

I'm building a website using a grid system as the framework. At first I had no problems with margins and padding, but now I have extra white space on the right side of my website.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/071ad2hg/1/

I already found the problem and it is from the following code:

```
.grid_12 { width: 100%; }
```

When I comment out this line the problem goes away, but I've used it in many places throughout my site and am wondering why this is happening all of a sudden. I would like to keep it as is and just fix it somehow.

Comment: Are you talking about the little 5px space on the left and the right of the image?

Comment: No, I'm referring to the large white space on the entire right side of the page.

Comment: it seems its not the .grid_12 is the source of your problem. try disabling `#images_row_1, #images_row_2, #images_iOS {
  margin-left: 25%;
}` or give value in px and see what happens

Comment: I commented out all of that code and still have the same error. Isn't % better than px for responsive design?

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse body has 8px margin you can change that by adding margin 0 to body css tag

demo http://jsfiddle.net/ckqkyaqd/

```
body {
    font-family: 'elegant_luxmager';
    color: #444948;
    margin:0;

}
```

Comment: If it worked, the horizontal lines would have reached the right side, but it did not. See what I mean?

Comment: @user3460974 have you seen that http://jsfiddle.net/ckqkyaqd/ ? lines filling 100% of window

Comment: I just checked again, the 2 white horizontal lines are not extending fully from left to right.

Comment: @user3460974 what browser are you using I've checked IE, chrome and FF and line filing all space ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59386/discussion-between-sylwester-and-user3460974).

Comment: I realized what it was. I was placing a grid within another grid that was at 100%. In other words if I have grid_12 that has a width of 100%, if I nest another div with width 30% inside of it, it will result in having that whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your body in the css.

`margin: 0;`

and set a pixel width for your grids.

```
.grid_12 {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 2% 1% 0;
float: left;
display: block;
}
```

I would suggest using a `.wrapper` instead.

```
.wrapper {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 1000px;
}

<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

---

**Found your issue:**

It's the 25% margin that adds the whitespace, use a wrapper to center that part or use `<center>`

```
#images_row_1, #images_row_2, #images_iOS {
 margin-left: 25%; 
}
```

Comment: So use a wrapper instead of the container div that will hold all the code within the body?

Comment: Using a wrapper will keep your code within the pixel size of the wrapper, let's say you set the wrapper width to 1000px and you use 100% in another class, the width of that class won't exceed the wrappers rule. @user3460974

Comment: When I use the wrapper, the content isn't the width I need. I need the all of the content to fill up the entire width of the page. When I change it to 1500px I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inspector in Google Chrome developer tools and see the order in which the CSS is being applied. You have this additional margin which is being applied to the div. Try using a wrapper div or better yet use a defined responsive framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

```
#images_row_1, #images_row_2, #images_iOS {
margin-left: 25%;
}
```